# How to give like operator of sql which matches any values given inside brackes seperated by commas and those values can be in any order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column say column Country where when I fire query values come like

```
|Country|
|US,UK,Canada|
|India,Pak,Bangladesh|
|Israel,Sudan,Africa|
```

Now when I filter out country using where such as

```
select * from country where Country = 'US,UK,Canada'
```

then it gives perfectly fine result like 
`|US,UK,Canada|`
but suppose Country column displays data like

```
|Country|
|Canada,UK,US|
|India,Pak,Bangladesh|
|Israel,Sudan,Africa|
```

then above query won't work.

I want a way by which it works when cell values separated by commas to be in any order be it like`Canada,UK,US or US,Canada,UK  etc .`

I don't know how to handle this using like operator of SQL

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not storing it , I got it fro client and I cant ask my client to change it , so I need to traverse it any how..

Answer (score 0):

Stroring CSV in column is an example of poor design. You should use complex type(array) or normalize your schema.

---

Workaround using array comparison(assuming all elements in column are unique):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ('{' || country || '}')::text[] AS a_country
  FROM Country
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE a_country <@ ('{' || 'Canada,UK,US' || '}')::text[]
  AND a_country @> ('{' || 'Canada,UK,US' || '}')::text[];
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a15f7c7d8a54da964aae9fd744fca1fe)**

Comment: is there a shorter way of doing this using like or in operators , I tried using your way in my code but its saying undefined character @